# jQuery mobile table reflow with name/value columns

Tags: jquery-mobile, html-table, reflow

jQuery mobile table reflow works for tables with THEAD. But for the table with name/value columns, for example,  4 columns without THEAD

```
Name:   John                ID:     00002
Age:    22                  Date：   2015-2-3
```

How to make it responsive?  Like the following on smart phones

```
Name:   John                
ID:     00002
Age:    22                  
Date：  2015-2-3
```

or

```
Name:   
John                
ID:     
00002
Age:    
22                  
Date：  
2015-2-3
```

Comment: check footable, for an automated way -- http://themergency.com/footable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a responsive grid rather than a table.  You can do this with the jQM listview and some CSS Media Queries to change the layout at different device widths.

The markup would be along these lines:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">Name:</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">John</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">ID:</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">00002</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">Age:</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">22</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">Date:</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">2015/2/3</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then Use CSS to make the list items float left at different breakpoints:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.my-page .ui-listview li .ui-block-a{
    color: #999;
}
.my-page .ui-listview li .ui-block-b{
    color: #111;
}

/* First breakpoint is 48em (768px). 2 column layout.  */
 @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .my-page .ui-listview li {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        border: rgb(221, 221, 221) solid 1px;
    }
}
/* Second breakpoint is 63.75em (1020px). 4 column layout.  */
 @media (min-width: 63.75em) {
    .my-page .ui-listview li {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7qtad6x2/1/)** with 3 breakpoints

Obviously you should tweak the breakpoints to fit your content...

Comment: Thanks. It works for mobile. But in our desktop version, jQueryMobile is not used.

Comment: @Dave, your question was about jQuery Mobile wasn't it?

Comment: Our desktop version and mobile version use the same code. Ideally with the same HTML code,  make it responsive with CSS. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave, you can apply the exact same idea to any listview. It does not have to be the jQM one. Just tweak the CSS as needed.

Comment: If I use table, how to style it? Thanks.